# TortoiseGit .git\info/exclude Open Faliure

Tags: tortoisegit

Can't ignore file in TortoiseGit. Error text is:

[image: .git\info/exclude Open Faliure]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `c:\Work\EmplyUp` a submodule and `c:\Work\EmplyUp\.git` a folder?

Comment: Do you have a File `c:\Work\EmplyUp\.git\info\exclude` (no extension)? If yes, can you open it with Notepad?

Comment: Fixed it. Solution in answer. Thanks. Weird that it was missing in the first place and that TortoiseGit didn't create it automatically.

Comment: Please report to the TortoiseGit developers next time: https://tortoisegit.org/issues

Comment: Why downvote? Explain reason at least. It is real problem & working solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder `info` and file `exclude` was missing. I created it manually and everything worked. Solution is based on `hinneLinks`'s comment. Thanks.